# The limit size does't work via $orderby with the index field using mongodb erlang driver

Tags: mongodb, erlang

Refer the following sample it works to query the limited size of documents,

```
run () ->
application:start (mongodb),
{ok, Conn} = mongo:connect (localhost),
{ok, Docs} = mongo:do (safe, master, Conn, test, fun() ->
    mongo:delete (foo, {}),
    mongo:insert_all (foo, [{x,1}, {x,2}, {x,3}, {x,0}, {x,-1}]),
    Cur = mongo:find (foo, {'$query', {}, '$orderby', {x,1}}, {'_id',0}, 0, 3),
    mongo:rest (Cur) end),
mongo:disconnect (Conn),
[{x,-1}, {x,0}, {x,1}] = Docs.
```

but if I ensure an index with x:

```
db.foo.ensureIndex({x:1})
```

the limit size will not work as expected, the query will return **all** matched documents.

I want to $orderby the index field with the limit size, could you please help explain what i miss? Thanks in advance!

BTW:the current official erlang driver is refactoring, i'm using the version of the erlang driver is 0.2.1

The original post is here

[Query return wrong result using mongdb erlang driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137178/query-return-wrong-result-using-mongdb-erlang-driver)

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the [syntax for `mongo:find/5`](http://api.mongodb.org/erlang/mongodb/mongo.html#find-5), it appears that the 5th parameter is ["batchSize"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#cursor-behaviors) not Limit.

The `batchSize` affects how many documents are fetched on each request to the server, but does not limit the total number of documents that will be returned.

I think what you actually want to call is a `Limit()` on the cursor similar to:

```
Cur = mongo:find (foo, {'$query', {}, '$orderby', {x,1}}, {'_id',0}).Limit(3)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply!Yes, I want to use the similar .limit() API for the cursor, but i don't find it refer the mongodb erlang driver doc/source.

Comment: And another question is that my above sample works fine if i didn't make an index with `{x:1}` when using `mongo:find/5`, the 5th parameter "batchSize" will return the same effect like "limitSize", but once add the index the testing code will return all matched documents(NOT the expected limited size) in order.

Comment: I'll have to test this a bit more ..ensuring an index shouldn't affect the batchSize.  What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: thanks a lot! I have tested the version of MongoDB "2.2.1" and "2.0.6", both of them have this issue, looks like it is an erlang driver issue in my opinion, because I tested with the python driver(pymongo-1.10.1) that an index won't affect the batchSize, please help verify.

Answer (score 0):

I also didn't find limit parameter in the api. I had the same issue as you mentioned. 
But I solved it by simply return result if the `Counter` reach `Limit` or return result if there are no more result.